# Why does python say this string is Type None

Tags: python, string, function, error-handling, numbers

I've made a function that converts a string into a number based off the type, and when I use it on a character it throws an error. Here it is:

```
def number(numstring):
    is_number = True
    
    for c in numstring:
        if not c in '123456789.':
        is_number = False
        
    if is_number:
        if_float = False

        for c in string:
            if c == '.':
                is_float = True
                break

        if is_float:
            return float(numstring)
        else:
            return int(numstring)
else:
    return None
```

and here's the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

How can I fix the error, and please explain the answer if you can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code and provide the full error traceback.

Comment: What is the line number of the error you get? What is the code on that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was some mistyping in your code
try this

```
def number(numstring):
    is_number = True
    
    for c in numstring:
        if not c in '123456789.':
            is_number = False
        
    if is_number:
        is_float = False

        for c in numstring:
            if c == '.':
                is_float = True
                break

        if is_float:
            return float(numstring)
        else:
            return int(numstring)
print( number("12.23") )
```

you can also use `try` as below

```
def number(numstring):
    try:
        x = float(numstring)
        return x
    except:
        try:
            x = int(numstring)
            return x
        except:
            return "wasn't a number"
        
print( number("12.23") )
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't see that. Thanks for answering this question!

Answer (score 0):

```
def number(numstring):
    is_number = True
    
    for c in numstring:
        if not c in '123456789.':
            is_number = False

    is_float = False
    
    if is_number:
        for c in numstring:
            if c == "." and not is_float:
                is_float = True
                break

        if is_float:
            return float(numstring)
        else:
            return int(float(numstring))
    else:
        return None
```

you declared the variable as `if_float` but used `is_float`. Also to convert a string to int you have to convert it to float first and then to int